# Deploying contract with parameters using web3.js and Node.js

Tags: web3js, contract-development, tokens, contract-deployment, nodejs

I try to deploy a ERC721 contract.
Which is from [OpenZeppelin.](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol)

My contract constructor wants two input string fields.

```
constructor(string _name, string _symbol) public {
    name_ = _name;
    symbol_ = _symbol;

    // register the supported interfaces to conform to ERC721 via ERC165
    _registerInterface(InterfaceId_ERC721Enumerable);
    _registerInterface(InterfaceId_ERC721Metadata);
}
```

However, when I'm deploying the contract, it tells me that the parameters I set must be HEX encoded data.

This is the error message i got:
`/Users/amos_mac/721_server/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileSync"](filename);if(!`

```
Error: The data field must be HEX encoded data.
```

So I used `web3.utils.asciiToHex()`, but it doesn't help.

Here is my code of deploying contract:

```
MyToken.deploy({
    arguments: [[web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top 10 Students')],[web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top10')]]
}).send({
    from: address,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    gas: gas + 500000
}).then((instance) => {
    console.log("Contract mined at " + instance.options.address);
});
```

Please help!
Thanks a lot!

---

After checking my code, I realized I added additional '0x' to my bytecode.
Thats what cause the bug.

Comment: try replacing `arguments: [[web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top 10 Students')],[web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top10')]]` with `arguments: [web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top 10 Students'),web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top10')]`

Comment: Hello Henk, thanks for leaving comment.
I tried  `arguments: [web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top 10 Students'),web3.utils.asciiToHex('Top10')]`,
but I still get the same error.
`Error: The data field must be HEX encoded data.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation of web3.eth.Contract.deploy](http://[The%20documentation%20of%20web3.eth.Contract.deploy](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy)) states that you have to provide the bytecode of the compiled smart contract along with the arguments:

```
MyToken.deploy({
    data: '0x[INSERT THE BYTECODE HERE]',
    // You can omit the asciiToHex calls, as the contstructor takes strings. 
    // Web3 will do the conversion for you.
    arguments: ['Top 10 Students','Top10'] 
}).send({
    from: address,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    gas: gas + 500000
}).then((instance) => {
    console.log("Contract mined at " + instance.options.address);
});
```

Comment: Henk, thanks again.
I provided my bytecode while declaring my contract:
`let MyToken = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), null, {
    data: '0x' + bytecode,
});`
Sorry that I didn't state this in my question.

Comment: Does `bytecode` by itself start with 0x? I

Comment: Ahh! I never notice that I already added 0x to the bytecode!
Thanks a lot!