# How to pass arguments to the constructor while testing an contract using web3

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I need to test my contract using `web3` and `ganache-cli`. In my contract, I have to send an `argument` to the `constructor` function. How to do it while deploying it with web3.

```
factory = await web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
    .deploy({
      data: compiledFactory.byteCode,
    })
    .send({
      from: accounts[0],
      gas: "1000000",
    });
```

And my contract is,

```
contract Factory{
    CrowdFunding[] public deployedContractAddresses;

    constructor(uint minimum) public {
        CrowdFunding newContract = new CrowdFunding(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedContractAddresses.push(newContract);
    }

    function getDeployedContractAddresses() public view returns(CrowdFunding[] memory) {
        return deployedContractAddresses;
    }
}
```

I have went through this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55594/deploying-contract-with-parameters-using-web3-js-and-node-js) in stack exchange, but I cannot able to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
.deploy({
  data: compiledFactory.byteCode,
})
```

To this:

```
.deploy({
  data: compiledFactory.byteCode,
  arguments: [arg1, arg2, arg3],
})
```

Where `arg1, arg2, arg3` are the constructor arguments by order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
factory = await web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
.deploy({
  data: compiledFactory.byteCode, 
  arguments: [100] //your argument
})
.send({
  from: accounts[0],
  gas: "1000000",
});
```

Comment: AFAIK, you should use an array of arguments (i.e., in your example, it should be `[100]`).