# Truffle - Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 2!

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, truffle-deployment

I have the below js script to deploy my contract to the Ropsten test network. I am using @truffle/hdwallet-provider v2.0.8 and web3.js v1.7.3.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const compiledContract = require('./build/Campaign.json');

// Hex encoded bytecode is in evm.bytecode.object
const bytecode = compiledContract.evm.bytecode.object;
const interface = compiledContract.abi;

provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
  },
  providerOrUrl: '<infura-node-url>'
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  try {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
      .deploy({ data: bytecode })
      .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);

    // To avoid deployment from hanging in the terminal
    provider.engine.stop();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

deploy();
```

However the same script works fine with web3.js v1.7.1 and @truffle/hdwallet-provider v2.0.4.

Stack trace:

```
Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 2!
(node:53572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 2!
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (/home/millennial97/Projects/kickstart-dapp/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:33:16)
    at Object._createTxObject (/home/millennial97/Projects/kickstart-dapp/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:694:22)
    at Contract.deploy (/home/millennial97/Projects/kickstart-dapp/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:525:33)
    at deploy (/home/millennial97/Projects/kickstart-dapp/ethereum/deploy.js:28:8
```

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the error, it seems that the contract you are deploying has some "constructor arguments". I cannot tell because you haven't shared the ABI or the contract code. Those arguments must be passed at deployment time

A would suggest you visiting this answer here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/55597/45721

and change your structure to follow this set-up

```
.deploy({
    data: '0x[INSERT THE BYTECODE HERE]',
    // You can omit the asciiToHex calls, as the contstructor takes strings. 
    // Web3 will do the conversion for you.
    arguments: ['Top 10 Students','Top10'] 
})
```